# Get top x "likes" using Facebook API

Tags: facebook

Is there a way to get the top likes of a particular section of a site? For example, I want to get all top x likes of example.com/directory. I'm not particular about which method (Graph, FQL, etc), I just want to find the best method.

Answer (score 0):

We currently do not support prefix queries for URLs or sorting by number of likes. If you have the set of URLs, you can use FQL and the http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat table to get the stats for each of them.